# Creating a DDL for a baseline for flyway

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, flyway

I've got an oracle 11 XE database, with 3 schemas in it, that I want to create a DDL file for to make a baseline script to use with flyway.

I've tried to export just the DDL of all 3 schemas, but the resulting sql doesn't include the creation of the users, or the creation of the tablespaces.  It just starts off with sql to create tables, which will not work as the users or the tablespaces don't exist.

Is there any way to do this with sql-developer or am I using the wrong tool for the job here?

I'm thinking I may need to include all the SYSTEM objects in the DDL, but no idea how importing that into a running oracle instance will work.

Any tips or hints I'd be grateful for, I'm starting to think this plan just isn't possible. :-(

Thanks

Matt

Comment: the tablespace isn't technically part of the schema, that's why they're not in there...you can grab the DDL for both, but not via the Export wizard

Comment: I just replied to Your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941316/is-it-possible-to-manage-an-oracle-database-with-flyway/57633332#54941316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we generate the ddl for a schema, we grab the schema objects, not the definition of the user that owns the schema, nor the tablespaces used IN the schema

you can still get those though, just open the DBA Panel -

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  So if I'm using flyway to create and drop the database from scratch, and you have to specify which schema's you work with in flyway, any ideas how' I'd manage tablespaces and users creation?  Would I have to include the SYSTEM schema or something?  Thanks again

Comment: please verify my answer to other @vandekerkoff question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941316/is-it-possible-to-manage-an-oracle-database-with-flyway/57633332#54941316