# Is it possible to manage an oracle database with flyway?

Tags: oracle, flyway

I'm really struggling to understand how I can use flyway to manage an oracle database.

The database in question has 3 schemas.

If I stipulate the 3 schemas in the flyway plugin definition in my gradle file, how do I manage the creation of the users themselves, and the tablespaces they use?

Any tips or suggestions would be more than welcome.

[Creating a DDL for a baseline for flyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931464/creating-a-ddl-for-a-baseline-for-flyway)

Comment: Tablespaces and users are usually created by the DBA, not by the application needing them. So that is typically not part of a  Flyway migration

Comment: Thanks for responding, @a_horse_with_no_name. So if I wanted to use flyway to create a database from scratch for use in a docker image, how would I manage that and use flyway to manage the resulting database?  Get a dump of the database with just the users and tablespaces, import that outside of flyway, then use flyway?  Does that sound sensible or a best practice approach?  If I add the sql for the tablespace and user creation into flyway scripts, it obviously fails as it can't clean them. thanks again

Comment: This would be achievable if selected scripts would be done by admin user, but that would be not secure, unless security would be properly limited. I have a similar concern now with database links, but this one is harder, because I don't want to put passwords in migration scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If You would create the DB with some limited super-user account, You could use it to create users and tablespaces, having a separate Flyway migration instance. That is:

1. Flyway migration by super-user from `sql/db-configuration/` using dedicated `flyway.conf`

   - creates users, tablespaces, and all other configuration
2. Flyway migration by application-user from `sql/app-code/` using dedicated `flyway.conf`

   - regular application code